# Require 50 reputation for asking question

Tags: discussion, reputation, asking-questions, limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [minimum rep before asking questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30048/minimum-rep-before-asking-questions)

In my opinion Stack Overflow is flooded by rather banal questions asked by users who just opened their Stack Overflow account. Would it make sense to restrict question asking rights for at least 50 reputation (or similar)?

Introducing this barrier would limit the number of irrelevant questions asked on Stack Overflow and at the same time increase the relevance of information on Stack Overflow.

What is your opinion on this topic?

Comment: Or: require one to know how to spell the site's name ;-)

Comment: It has now (for me at least) begun: the "we need more restrictions!  Freedom is bad, people can't deal with it!  And *I* am past that barrier, so raise it higher!"

Comment: +1, but only if you get 50 rep by going to the faq page and scrolling to the bottom.

Comment: @Will **Every time**

Answer (score 19):

Most new users are here to ask questions. Besides, it is intentionally that you don't have anything (not even an account) to ask a question.

So setting a 50 rep barrier violates one of the basic principle of the site.

But there are some projects to filter bad questions (and answers). And if all fails, there are still users with closing privileges and moderators to clean the mess.

Answer (score 10):

Most people join stackoverflow to find answers to the questions they have. So in my opinion, its not wise to restrict them to post questions when they are new.

You can still use the flagging option if you find unsuitable questions or leave a comment for others with high reputation to see and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good idea, because there are many good question from first time users that would not be allowed.  In fact if there was a 50 rep limit, you would have not been able to ask this question if it was not for you 100 rep bonus.