# Minimal reputation to ask a question

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [minimum rep before asking questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30048/minimum-rep-before-asking-questions)

I see a lot of questions asked in such an awful manner, without any formatting or even English grammar. And most of them are asked by people with 1 rep. They don't even try to make their questions clear and easy to read.

So, my question is: why should we deal with such big amount of badly asked questions? Should we make people answer a couple of questions and earn some little rep (10 for example) to ask a question by themselves?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30048/minimum-rep-before-asking-questions

Comment: Minimum reputation is big No as discussed in the duplicate question. Other alternative to deal with bad questions is to grant reputation for editing a question or taking part in closing it - this will cause more members with enough rep to make the effort and fix bad grammar and close really bad questions.